# How to construct list comprehension, needing to access multiple elements in list during each iteration?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

How can one write a list comprehension that accesses each element of a list, **and the 2 adjacent on either side**?

I would like to access each element, and 2 adjacent on either side, apply a function, and return the result as the new value of the list.

In a for loop, it is easy:

```
lst=[1, 30, 40, 2, 7, 8, 9, 22, 7, 8, 44, 39, 2, 1, 0, 88, 17]

for ii in list(range(3,len(lst)-3)):
    vals=lst[ii-2:ii+3]
    new_val=np.mean(vals)
    lst[ii]=new_val
```

How would one access these elements in a list comprehension - i.e. without being able to access via element position?

Comment: Intention is to speed up the loop! Processing in the loops takes a very long time.

Comment: Changing the loop to a list comprehension won't help much with the performance.

Comment: Considering that you're using NumPy, you shouldn't be using lists or list comprehensions at all. (Also, the `new_val` computation is using a mix of old and new values, which doesn't seem to be the intention.)

Comment: You can do this, in some remarkably convoluted way, but you should just use a for-loop. The potential speed ups from a for-loop to a list comprehension are marginal, and indeed, since you are modifying a list in-place, it might actually be slower to use a comprehension, which necessarily materializes an auxilliary list

Comment: Also, why, oh why, are you iterating over `list(range(3,len(lst)-3))`??? This is just unecessarily inefficient, just iterate over `range(3, len(lst)-3)`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! Haven't used for loops on lists much :)

Comment: @user2357112 Why are lists not good with Numpy?  My actual dataset is a pandas dataframe with 245,395 rows... I'm trying to smooth the series in a for loop. Should have written the Q with a pandas series I guess. Thanks for the help! I guess any tips on speeding this up... seems like such a simple operation, on a  not-too-large dataset, takes several minutes to run!

Comment: If you are using lists inside `numpy` arrays, the you are loosing all speed/space advantage of `numpy`

Comment: @EHB a list-comprehension is essentially a for-loop with some minor optimizations. You should use it primarily for *clarity* when you want to *create a new list*, i.e. a functional transformation. Here, you are modifying a list in-place, and each modification depends on the previous one. There won't be a clean way to accomplish this with a list comprehension, and thus, you should just use the loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can I accept your comment as the answer? I don't see how to do that, this is my first SO question. If you can post as an answer I would accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @EHB: List-based code doesn't take advantage of the benefits of NumPy, and it's prone to weird failures and incompatibilities (for example, not broadcasting, or accidentally making an object array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to show a useful pattern, the list comp can use `zip` of lagged index slices of `lst`

```
lst=[1, 30, 40, 2, 7, 8, 9, 22, 7, 8, 44, 39, 2, 1, 0, 88, 17]

[sum(vals)/3. for vals in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:])]
Out[8]: 
[23.666666666666668,
 24.0,
 16.333333333333332,
 5.666666666666667,
 8.0,
 13.0,
 12.666666666666666,
 12.333333333333334,
 19.666666666666668,
 30.333333333333332,
 28.333333333333332,
 14.0,
 1.0,
 29.666666666666668,
 35.0]
```

a numpy solution:

```
np.convolve(lst, [1/3., 1/3., 1/3.], 'valid')
Out[11]: 
array([ 23.66666667,  24.        ,  16.33333333,   5.66666667,
         8.        ,  13.        ,  12.66666667,  12.33333333,
        19.66666667,  30.33333333,  28.33333333,  14.        ,
         1.        ,  29.66666667,  35.        ])
```